# looking for the best jquery message plugin / low opacity / mouse click -> disappear / favorite position

Tags: jquery, plugins, messagebox

i found the below plugin for showing messages ...

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-message/

we can change the position of message in css file...(perfect)

but my problem is i couln't find a correct way (changing the plugin) for dissapearing message by mouse click.

i could n't trace some lines of this simple plugin.(about timeout)

would u plz:

1-lead me to a better plugin with more effects

2-help me to change this plugin for mouse click (on message , not window) dissapear

the simple upper plugin code is like this :

```
(function($) {
    var helper,
        visible,
        timeout1,
        timeout2;

    $.fn.message = function(message) {
        message = $.trim(message || this.text());
        if (!message) {
            return;
        }
        clearTimeout(timeout1);
        clearTimeout(timeout2);

        initHelper();
        helper.find("p").html(message);
        helper.show().animate({ opacity: $.message.defaults.opacity}, $.message.defaults.fadeInDuration);
        visible = true;
        active = false;
        %%%++++timeout1 = setTimeout(function() {
            visible = false;
        }, $.message.defaults.minDuration + $.message.defaults.displayDurationPerCharacter * Math.sqrt(message.length));
        %%%++++timeout2 = setTimeout(fadeOutHelper, $.message.defaults.totalTimeout);
    };

    function initHelper() {
        if (!helper) {
            helper = $($.message.defaults.template).appendTo(document.body);
            %%%++++$(window).bind("mousemove click keypress", fadeOutHelper);
        }
    }

    function fadeOutHelper() {
        if (helper.is(":visible") && !helper.is(":animated") && !visible) {
            helper.animate({ opacity: 0 }, $.message.defaults.fadeOutDuration, function() { $(this).hide() })
        }
    }

    $.message = {};
    $.message.defaults = {
        opacity: 0.8,
        fadeOutDuration: 500,
        fadeInDuration: 200,
        displayDurationPerCharacter: 125,
        minDuration: 2500,
        totalTimeout: 6000,
        template: '<div class="jquery-message"><div class="round"></div><p></p><div class="round"></div></div>'
    }
})(jQuery);
```

it seems i should change the %%%++++ lines for mouse click dissappear / but how ?

thanks for attention

Comment: Can you cut the code to only the relevant parts?

Comment: Make it more readable, skipp all we don't need here ;)

Comment: dear @Caspar Kleijne / i edit my Q!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jGrowl](http://nick.boldison.com/websites/jquery/jgrowl-jquery-alerts-and-message-box/)** is an awesome plug-in.  It has quite a few options that make it configurable. Give it a whirl.

*PS, if you want it to stick until the user clicks on it, you'll want to enable the sticky option.*